# Angular Js HTML 5 Routing Configuration Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, url-routing

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

HTML 5 Routing is enabled in my app, the problem is I am not able to use jQuery dropdowns. Another issue is whenever the browser refreshes the page, it goes to `404` page , have anyone found any solution?

Comment: checkout the docs, it says `.html5Mode(true);` requires server side setup, so you need to have some setups with `.htaccess` file.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: but for dropdowns requiring href="#id" how i can use ?